# Encoding error when writing out weekday name in swedish (PHP/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime, strftime, setlocale

Any idea why I get an encoding error with this code?

```
$date_pre = get_field("date");
$date_s = date("j/n", strtotime($date_pre));

setlocale(LC_TIME,'sv_SE');
$month = strtolower(strftime("%B", strtotime($date_pre)));
$date_l = strftime("%A %e " . $month, strtotime($date_pre));
```

The `$date_pre` is a ACF field that contains a date formated like this: `20180518`. When I then echo out `$date_l`, which is a reformated variant of `$date_pre` that puts in the weekday in swedish with the day number and the name of the month (`Lördag 18 maj`), it can’t write out “åäö“. "ÅÄÖ" gets replaced with a question mark symbol. It works on my local setup, but not when I upload the theme to a server.

Comment: Does your webserver output it as UTF-8?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/5914775) and ignore the database part of it.